# unable to use nested list as a parameter

Tags: python, list, nested

am using nested lists with key to store tv channels' info, while the nested list works fin when using straight, but would cause an error if used as a parameter in a function here is sample of my code

`print(get_List()[1]['name'])` ---> output:
Harley Davidson Racing TV (720p) [Not 24/7]

calling it from function

```
def get_AllName(list):
    channel_names = []
    x=0
    while x<len(list):
        channel_names.append(list()[x]['name'])
        x+=1
    return channel_names
print(get_AllName(get_List()))
```

I get this error
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You are not allowed to do this: `list()`. Parenthesis are used to call a function, but a list is not a function and therefore not `callable`. Just use `list[x]['name']`

Answer (score 0):

`list`, as a type, is actually a callable (contrary to what is suggested in the comments), and can be called as `list()` - it just returns an empty list though. So `list()[x]['name']` is effectively `[][x]['name']` and since the first list is empty, there's nothing to be indexed with `x`.

`get_List()` apparently returns a list of dictionaries, so to get a list of names:

```
def get_names(xs):
    return[x['name'] for x in xs]


print(get_names(get_List()))
```

Or, without the extra function:

```
print([x['name'] for x in get_List()])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to name variables with data types or special keywords.
Instead of a `list`, try naming it as `List` or `whole_list` or `something`.

Your code will convert to:

```
def get_AllName(whole_list):
    channel_names = []
    x=0
    while x<len(whole_list):
        channel_names.append(whole_list[x]['name'])
        x+=1
    return channel_names
print(get_AllName(get_List()))
```